# Intertia modal - load view into a model for create, edit etc

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5, inertiajs, bootstrap5-modal

Im using Laravel 9 with inertia. The design of the project includes modals for creating, updating but i see that inertia doesnt have support for modals?

I have found a few projects for inertia modals but they dont seem to work.

Currently when you navigate using inertia, Laravel hits the route and then in the controller you render an inertia page and vue knows to find a specific page and then navigates to that new page (loads it in a new vue page)

I am wanting to do the same but instead of a new page loaded i want to remain on the same parent page and load the new route content into a modal.

Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure i really understood what you want to do, but inertia is used a a middleware between  your vue frontend and your laravel backend, so if you want to use modals, you have to make your own ones or you have to use packages such as vuetify, mdbootstrap and so on. I made a project with inertia, vue and laravel where i used modals, you can check it here: https://github.com/michaelcozzolino/cinediary

Comment: @Mike I want to have one modal that I can load any laravel view into without using axios. I want inertia to render the view inside a modal. Just like you click a link to a laravel resource but it would display a modal and not a new page

Comment: @Mike nice project. Just a comment on the way you load pages on your project. You arent using the inertia link so the page is refreshing which it shouldnt be doing.

Comment: ok I got your point, normally i would use axios to put the data in my view. I tried to find something on the web, but i'm not sure what i found is what you need: https://larsklopstra.nl/blog/route-based-modals-with-laravel-inertiajs-and-vuejs

Comment: thanks for your feedback about my project! actually i'm using mdbootstrap vue, so if you don't see inertia links in the 95% of the project is because mdbootstrap vue is supposed to use the inertia router in this case, but i might be wrong (i'm new to inertia). Actually i checked (in the browser) with the demo inertia app that the pages are loaded in the same way. anyway I don't want to go off topic here and if you want to have a talk with me you can drop me an email: me@michaelcozzolino_it (replace '_' with '.')

Answer (score 1):

If you want a blade view to be loaded inside a modal in an Inertia page you can do:

```
$modalContent = view('your-blade-view-name', $modalData)->render();
return Inertia::render('inertia-page', $inertiaData);
```

[I created a demo repository for this](https://github.com/michaelcozzolino/inertia-blade-view-inside-modal)